# Create an email form sending a link to a specific .zip file from my server

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I would like to create a form in `html` where the user enters **name**, **company**, **e-mail** and **country**.

When submitting the form, the user will get an e-mail to his/hers e-mail address with a specific link to a **.zip file** from my server.

The zip file will change name every quarter, so for instance, this quarter it's ***"download/R2014.1.zip"***, next is ***"download/R2014.2.zip".***

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Seeing the tags you chose, you seem to know which tool to use. I would suggest for you to try, write some code, and come back here if you face a problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating the email via sendmessage in PHP. When building up the message text, try something like this:

```
$currentMonth = date("m", time());
$curentQuarter = ceil($currentMonth/3);
$filename = 'R' . date("Y") . '.' . $currentQuarter . '.zip';

$link = '<a href="www.youraddress.com/download/' . $filename . '/">Download this zip file</a>';

$message = 'Some Email Text. ' . $link . ' Rest of email.'
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks muri!Very kind of you!

Comment: If it helped, I would ask you to upvote or accept my answer please =)